# Seamlessly switch between ethernet and wifi

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, ethernet

At home, depending on room, signal pertubation (many Wifi networks around), and phase of the moon I connect to the modem/router with Ethernet or Wifi. In practice this means either Wifi alone, or Wifi+Ethernet (in which case all traffic goes through the Ethernet interface).

If I change rooms I may have to add/remove the Ethernet link. However this usually breaks any connection (VPN, in particular). The only case where things work OK are adding the Ethernet with an HTTP download in progress (the download switches to the Ethernet interface all by itself).

Is there some utility or network manager setting/manoeuver that I could use to prepare the switch and prevent breaking existing connections?

Strangely these connections will very often survive an Ethernet interruption (unplug Ethernet, move swiftly to other room, plug back Ethernet), even with Wifi switched off.

Comment: Possibly playing with the "metric" of the interfaces?